# Replace cell value with it's visible value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list, that Excel keeps formatting as a date.  The cells show the following (so this is the "visible" value):

```
06-14
06-01
05-14
10-01
....
```

These are *not* to be dates.  However, Excel keeps formatting them as such, so the formula bar for the first one shows `06/14/2020`.  I want the formula bar to show `06-14` (or, to be technical, this is okay too `'06-14`).  I don't want a date in the Formula bar.

I've tried VBA, but none of these do it:

```
Cells(1,1).Value = Cells(1,1).Text
Cells(1,1).Value = Cells(1,1).Value
```

It keeps the date in the formula bar.

Changing the cell's format to say `Text` just puts the full date number in the cell, e.g. `44138`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, just do:

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "'" & Cells(1,1).Text
```

Comment: FYI - Just as I submitted the question, the answer dawned on me.  If this is a duplicate Q, let me know and I can delete.